# Using JSON-based Database for unordered data

Tags: json, mongodb, database

I am working on a simple app for Android. I am having some trouble using the Firebase database since it uses JSON objects and I am used to relational databases.

My data will consists of two users that share a value. In relational databases this would be represented in a table like this:

```
**uname1**  **uname2** shared_value
```

In which the usernames are the keys. If I wanted the all the values user Bob shares with other users, I could do a simple union statement that would return the rows where:

```
uname1 == Bob or unname == Bob
```

However, in JSON databases, there seems to be a tree-like hierarchy in the data, which is complicated since I would not be able to search for users at the top level. I am looking for help in how to do this or how to structure my database for best efficiency if my most common search will be one similar to the one above.

In case this is not enough information, I will elaborate: My database would be structured like this:

```
{
     'username': 'Bob' 
            {
                   'username2': 'Alice'
                         {
                               'shared_value' = 2
                         }
            }
      'username': 'Cece'
            {
                   'username2': 'Bob'
                         {
                               'shared_value' = 4
                         }
            }
```

As you can see from the example, Bob is included in two relationships, but looking into Bobs node doesn't show that information. (The relationship is commutative, so who is "first" cannot be predicted).

The most intuitive way to fix this would be duplicate all data. For example, when we add Bob->Alice->2, also add Alice->Bob->2. In my experience with relational databases, duplication could be a big problem, which is why I haven't done this already. Also, duplication seems like an inefficient fix.

Comment: How you model your data is a matter of opinion. And there's no requirement at all to have nested (hierarchical) data within a document. That's just one possibility, as is referenced documents.

Comment: That's not valid JSON. What's the tag on your subdocuments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a reason why you don't invert this? How about a collection like:

```
{ "_id": 2, "usernames":[ "Bob", "Alice"]}
{ "_id": 4, "usernames":[ "Bob", "Cece"]}
```

If you need all the values for "Bob", then index on "usernames".

EDIT:

If you need the two usernames to be a unique key, then do something like this:

```
{ "_id": {"uname1":"Bob", "uname2":"Alice"}, "value": 2 }
```

But this would still permit the creation of:

```
{ "_id": {"uname1":"Alice", "uname2":"Bob"}, "value": 78 }
```

(This issue is also present in your as-is relational model, btw. How do you handle it there?)

In general, I think implementing an array by creating multiple columns with names like `"attr1"`, `"attr2"`, `"attr3"`, etc. and then having to search them all for a possible value is an artifact of relational table modeling, which does not support array values. If you are converting to a document-oriented storage, these really should be an embedded list of values, and you should use the document paradigm and model them as such, instead of just reimplementing your table rows as documents.

Comment: Maybe this is my bias in coming from sql or my misunderstanding, but wouldn't this allow me to have various entires with the Bob Alice combination? The two usernames should be a key

Comment: You are right, the relational model would still have this problem. I guess I didn't find that to be a problem since a union statement is so straightforward I didn't even notice it. I think I'm going to use your suggested structure, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can still have old structure:

```
[
    { username: 'Bob', username2: 'Alice', value: 2 },
    { username: 'Cece', username2: 'Bob', value: 4 },
]
```

You may want to create indexes on 'username' and 'username2' for performance. And then just do the same union.

Comment: You are completely right. However, this doesn't prevent me from having two entries with 'Bob' and "Alice', which should be a key.

Answer (score 0):

To create a tree-like structure, the best way is to create an "ancestors" array that stores all the ancestors of a particular entry. That way you can query for either ancestors or descendants and all documents that are related to a particular value in the tree. Using your example, you would be able to search for all descendants of Bob's, or any of his ancestors (and related documents).

The answer above suggest:

```
{ "_id": {"uname1":"Bob", "uname2":"Alice"}, "value": 2 }
```

That is correct. But you don't get to see the relationship between Bob and Cece with this design. My suggestion, which is from Mongo, is to store ancestor keys in an ancestor array.

```
{ "_id": {"uname1":"Bob", "uname2":"Alice"}, "value": 2 , "ancestors": [{uname: "Cece"}]}
```

With this design you still get duplicates, which is something that you do not want. I would design it like this:

```
{"username": "Bob", "ancestors": [{"username": "Cece", "shared_value": 4}]}
{"username": "Alice", "ancestors": [{"username": "Bob", "shared_value": 2}, {"username": "Cece"}]}
```